# blacklistd not blocking addresses

Tags: freebsd, bsd, pf

I've enabled the [PF(4) firewall](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) and [blacklistd(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=blacklistd&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports). Although IP addresses are being added to to blacklist, I can still see multiple failed attempts from a single IP address. Yet when I test it myself, my IP address gets blacklisted properly: it's added to the blacklist and I can't initiate any more connections from it.

#### /etc/rc.conf:

```
blacklistd_enable="YES"
pf_enable="YES"
```

#### /etc/blacklistd.conf:

```
# adr/mask:port type    proto   owner           name    nfail   disable
[local]
ssh             stream  *       *               *       1       365d
# Extra lines removed
```

#### /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
...
UseBlacklist Yes
...
```

#### /etc/pf.conf:

```
intf="wlan0"
set skip on { lo0, em0 }

# Packet normalization
scrub in

# Integrate blacklistd to protect sshd
anchor "blacklistd/*" in on $intf

### FIREWALL RULES

# Default firewall rules
block in
pass out
# Allow inbound SSH on the default port (22)
pass in on $intf proto tcp to ($intf) port 22
# Allow basic ICMP functionality
pass in on $intf inet proto icmp to ($intf) icmp-type { unreach, redir, timex, echoreq }
```

#### grep sshd /var/log/messages | tail -20

```
Mar  2 00:21:11 [...] illegal user admin from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:21:30 [...] illegal user alix from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:21:51 [...] illegal user gotubego from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:23:35 [...] illegal user tsbot from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:23:40 [...] illegal user spravce from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:25:34 [...] root from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:25:57 [...] illegal user admin from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:27:29 [...] illegal user admin from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:29:13 [...] root from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:30:06 [...] root from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:33:09 [...] illegal user admin from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:33:23 [...] illegal user admin from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:34:15 [...] illegal user bogalfb from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:35:34 [...] root from 120.92.147.56
Mar  2 00:35:59 [...] illegal user admin from 120.92.147.56
Mar  3 13:35:35 [...] illegal user user from 103.200.23.124
Mar  4 19:47:59 [...] root from 111.207.23.140
Mar  5 02:09:39 [...] illegal user user from host2.awolphoto.com
Mar  5 16:02:33 [...] illegal user user from 103.221.221.189
Mar  7 04:43:38 [...] illegal user user from server28.pixeled.net
```

I've truncated the lines for readability. The entire first lines reads as:

```
Mar  2 00:21:11 phoenix sshd[94473]: error: PAM: authentication error for illegal user admin from 120.92.147.56
```

I've deleted the unuseful bits.

#### sudo blacklistctl dump -br

```
 150.95.156.167/32:22   OK      2/1     1y3d22h45m57s
  27.79.178.252/32:22   OK      2/1     1y3d29h16m55s
  194.61.24.162/32:22   OK      40/1    20d2h19m32s
 76.242.160.219/32:22   OK      2/1     22d42h8m58s
 91.121.173.184/32:22   OK      2/1     2d12h1m40s
116.127.174.152/32:22   OK      2/1     7d34h39m45s
   88.214.26.49/32:22   OK      62/1    9d11h56m22s
...
```

The list contains 1069 entries but not the IP address `120.92.147.56`.

## Questions

1. Some IP addresses time out in (more) a year (as they should) while others time out in only a couple of days (e.g. 2 days).
2. Some IP addresses (e.g. `120.92.147.56`) are *not* added to the list while they clearly should be.
3. Some addresses could execute as much as 62 attempts before being blocked in the list.

What am I missing in my configuration to make it work as desired?

Comment: From reading [`blacklistd.conf(5)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=blacklistd.conf&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports), it looks like the first field on the line in the `blacklistd.conf` file should be prefixed by `:` if it's to be taken as a port. I'm not on FreeBSD so I can't test this though. You may want to test with `:ssh` or `wlan0:ssh`.

Comment: I could give that a try. I copied it from _Absolute FreeBSD, 3rd edition_ without the colon and it appears to work most of the time. It's adding IP addresses to the blocked list and when I test it, it blocks me correctly.

Comment: Yeah, it's the only thing that stood out for me. I can't say anything more really.

Answer (score 0):

My configuration is pretty much the same and I can't see any sshd "... illegal user ..." in /var/log/messages

The only differences are in my rc.conf

```
blacklistd_flags="-r"
```

and in pf.conf. Instead of

```
pass in on $intf proto tcp to ($intf) port 22
```

you might consider this one

```
pass in on $intf proto tcp from any to any port ssh flags S/SA synproxy state
```

FWIW. To make the configuration reproducible I use my [Ansible role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/freebsd_pf)

Notes

- Entry "88.214.26.49/32:22   OK      62/1    9d11h56m22s" looks suspicious. Should have been blacklisted after 1st failure. How did it manage to fail 62 times?
- Entry "194.61.24.162/32:22   OK      40/1    20d2h19m32s" dtto
- You configured to disable for "365d", but the entries above show remaining times in couple of days. Have these entries really been blacklisted over 11 months?